# Combine queries from 2 inherited Django models

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-polymorphic

I would like to perform a prefetch. The point is: I have a baseModel and inherited models that are liked to other models. But my baseModel isn't linked with them.
Here is the speudo code:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Movie(PolymorphicModel):
    title = models.CharField()
    author = models.ForeignKey('Author')

class EnglishMovie(Movie):
    pass

class FrenchMovie(Movie):
    pass

class Subtitle(models.Model):
    movie = models.ForeignKey('FrenchMovie', related_name='subtitle')
    text = models.CharField()
```

As you can see, FrenchMovie is linked to subtitles, but EnglishMovie isn't.
I would like to prefetch all my movie, and prefetch the subtitles as well.
I've tried several methods:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Movie.objects.prefetch_related('author', 'subtitle').all()
```

I get: **ValueError: Cannot query "EnglishMovie object (1)": Must be "FrenchMovie" instance.**

```
def get_queryset(self):
    q1 = Movie.objects.prefetch_related('author').all()
    q2 = FrenchMovie.objects.prefetch_related('subtitle').all()
    return q1 | q2
```

I get: **AssertionError: Cannot combine queries on two different base models.**

Any tips ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: you can't combine from two different models. You can use `itertools.chain` to combine two queryset(by converting them to list), but it won't work in `get_queryset`.

Comment: @ruddra I've tried that: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'model'.
But why it isn't working in get_queryset specialy ?

Comment: Sorry, I might have explained in wrong way. `get_queryset` is expected to return a queryset, not a list. So any method which is using `get_queryset` will not work because they will get a list from it.